# Cropping a minibatch of images in Pytorch -- each image differently

Tags: pytorch

I have a tensor named `input` with dimensions 64x21x21. It is a minibatch of 64 images, each 21x21 pixels. I'd like to crop each image down to 11x11 pixels. So the output tensor I want would have dimensions 64x11x11.

I'd like to crop each image around a different "center pixel." The center pixels are given by a 2-dimensional long tensor named `center` with dimensions 64x2. For image i, `center[i][0]` gives the row index and `center[i][1]` gives the column index for the pixel that should be at the center in the output. We can assume that the center pixel is always at least 5 pixels away from the border.

Is there an efficient way to do this in pytorch (on the gpu)?

UPDATE: Let me clarify that the `center` tensor is formed by a deep neural network. It acts as a "hard attention mechanism," to use the reinforcement learning term for it. After I "crop" an image, that subimage becomes the input to another neural network. That's why I want to do the cropping in Pytorch: because the operations before and after the cropping are in Pytorch. I'd like to avoid having to transfer anything from the GPU back to the CPU.

Comment: Why dont you give a try to pytorch's transform method?

Comment: You can do this in image pre-processing stage, then feed the batch of images into network. That is the way pytorch works.

Comment: During preprocessing I won't know know the `center` tensor yet, unfortunately. The values of `center` change every iteration.

Answer (score 2):

I raised the question over on the pytorch forums, and got an answer there from smth. The `grid_sample` function should totally solve the problem.

https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/cropping-a-minibatch-of-images-each-image-a-bit-differently/12247

Answer (score 0):

[torchvision](http://pytorch.org/docs/master/torchvision/transforms.html) contains transforms including `RandomCrop`, but it doesn't seem to fit your use case if you want the images cropped in a specific way. I would recon that PyTorch, a deep learning framework, is not the appropriate tool for cropping images.

Instead, have a look at [this tutorial](http://matthiaseisen.com/pp/patterns/p0202/) that uses [pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.0.0/). You should be able to implement your use case with this. Also have a look at [pillow-simd](https://github.com/uploadcare/pillow-simd) which does some operations faster.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Unfortunately I don't think this will work for me: I won't know what region to crop until I've run pytorch to get the `center` tensor, so I can't crop the image during pre-processing with pillow. I can't do it with pillow in post-processing either, because I have to process the cropped images with pytorch too.

Comment: Alright, I see. I guess you'll have to implement the operation yourself then